# PDOStatement to JSON

Tags: php, json, pdo

How would I convert a `PDOStatement` to JSON?

I need to jsonify a `PDO::FETCH_OBJ`.

`json_encode` does not have the ability to jsonify a `PDO::FETCH_OBJ`.

Comment: Which `PDOStatement` are you referring to?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can use the inbuilt php function json_encode() http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

To encode the results use something like

```php
<?php
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=database;host=127.0.0.1", "user", "password");
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM table");
$statement->execute();
$results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json = json_encode($results);
```

Comment: did you just json_encode a PDOStatement object?

Comment: Yes I did which sort of works, when decoding it returns a stdClass object.

@mediaslave you can use json_encode on PDO::FETCH_OBJ, when you run PDO::FETCH_OBJ it creates objects of the stdClass, these can then be encoded into json objects which then decode back into stdClass objects. Do some var_dumps on your results and see :)

Comment: `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` really important otherwise you will have double informations

Comment: So should we use FETCH_OBJ or FETCH_ASSOC?

Comment: In my case I used da MySQL database with the collation `utf8_unicode_ci`. For some reason json_encode told me,`Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded`. I had to convert the `$results` array to unicode (again?), now it is working.

Answer (score 12):

Use the [`fetchAll()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) method of the PDOStatement to retrieve an array of the values, and then pass that to [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

```
$resultJSON = json_encode($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$array = $statement->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
$json = json_encode( $array );
```

Answer (score 3):

I have also found it very useful to insert and set the PHP header('Content-Type: application/json') prior to sending back the JSON object returned by json_encode()

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and also, how does setting that header helps at all before doing a decode? If you could explain that it could fit in a comment (over even editing) in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this may be it's help you

```
 $data = array();
        if($stmt->execute()){
          while ($row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $data['data'] = $row;
            }
          }
      }
    
    if(!empty($data)){
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");//this allows cors
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        print json_encode($data);
    }else{
      echo 'error';
    }
```