# not able to json_encode PDO result

Tags: pdo, json

I can't `json_encode` my array returned from PDO:

`var_dump(json_encode($result));` returns `false`

I have also reassigned this array to a new array, looping through the PDO result.

Here is my code:

```
$host = "localhost";
$database = "test";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

$db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};port:3306;dbname={$database}", $username, $password);
!$db && exit("Database connect failed");
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT sample.* FROM test.sample LIMIT 10");
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump(json_encode($result));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PDOStatement to json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770273/pdostatement-to-json)

Comment: yes it's duplicate but as you can see i have tried same code and still this is not working .. and i think you also have tried this !!!!

Comment: @hd1 as you can also see that answer to that is question here.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the same problem, found out that the $result itself is error/false.
you should check the content of your $result, using

```
print_r($result);
```

if it is so (still false), you should your database coneection or your syntax query.