# Mysql to JSON specific rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

There is a MySQL database, with the **"events" table**. In that table I have over 250 rows, with different events, **name, ID, location, and start time**. I know how to get all the data from that table, but I want to learn how to get specific rows.

How can I get the rows with start_time today?

My code:

```
//Create Database connection
$db = mysql_connect("####","####","####");
if (!$db) {
    die('Could not connect to db: ' . mysql_error());
}

//Select the Database

mysql_select_db("rlidi37_timisoara",$db);

$result = mysql_query("select * from events", $db); 

//Create an array
$json_response = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

    $row_array['name'] = $row['name'];
    $row_array['location'] = $row['location'];
    $row_array['id'] = $row['id'];
    $row_array['start_time'] = $row['start_time'];

    //push the values in the arr
    array_push($json_response,$row_array);

}

echo json_encode($json_response);
//Close the database connection
fclose($db);
```

Comment: Yes... and you should use `mysqli`, `mysql` is depreciated. Object Oriented style saves typing. Your question is too vague.

Comment: $result = mysql_query("select * from events where start_time>=CURDATE()", $db);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First modify your query to add a WHERE clause to filter down the results. Then once you have the results, you can turn it into JSON 1 of 2 ways.

1. If you are using plain php mysql functions, I think you have to iterate over the data to create an array of arrays where each records is an associative array. Then you can call json_encode on that 2D array.
2. If you are using PDO, check out the PDO::FETCH_OBJ option. See this Stack Overflow question: [PDOStatement to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770273/pdostatement-to-json)