# Binding a javascript dynamic content into another javascript dynamic content

Tags: javascript, html

I have a select field that I can dynamically add and remove, and this select field also dynamically list down its values, retrieved from MySQL database using PHP.
I did not include the PHP code, but it is working, I can perfectly retrieve the data and display in the drop downs.
Here is a reference code on how I retrieve the data, the answer to the question:

[PDOStatement to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770273/pdostatement-to-json)

And also, I found this, I am not sure if this is applicable, but the answer in the question looks promising, I am just not sure how to apply and test it.

```
"Because it's dynamic content, you can't bind events like the static content, it will not bind to the elements because they don't appear at the time you bind. So you should bind event like this:

$('#parent').on('click', 'a.remove_block', function(events){
   $(this).parents('div').eq(1).remove();
 });
```

The problem is how can I be able to apply the dynamic drop down on each instance, I mean every time I add an additional select field. I also included a snippet here to help visualize.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  var maxRows = 100;
  var x = 1;
  var json_url = "books_json.php";

  var html = '';
  html += '<tr>';
  html += '<td>';
  html += '<select name="book_title[]" id="book_title">';
  html += '<option value="" selected></option>';
  html += '</select>';
  html += '</td>';
  html += '<td>';
  html += '<select name="book_author[]" id="book_author">';
  html += '<option value="" selected></option>';
  html += '</select>';
  html += '</td>';
  html += '<td>';
  html += '<input type="number" step=0.01 name="amount[]"/>';
  html += '</td>';
  html += '<td>';
  html += '<button type="button" id="remove">Remove</button>';
  html += '</td>';
  html += '</tr>';

      jQuery.getJSON(json_url, function(data) {
      // empty contents of dropdown
      $("#book_title").html("");
      $("#book_title").append("<option value='' selected></option>");
      // put new dropdown values to dropdown
      jQuery.each(data, function(key, val) {
        $("#book_title").append('<option value="' + val.book_title + '"data-book_title_id="' + val.book_title_id + ' ">' + val.book_title + '</option>')
      });
    });

  $("#add").click(function(e) {
    if (x <= maxRows) {
      $("#book_table").append(html);
      x++;
    }
  });

  $("#book_table").on('click', '#remove', function(e) {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    x--;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='book_table'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Author</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select name="book_title[]" id="book_title">
          <option value='' selected></option>
        </select>
      </td>

      <td>
        <select name="book_author[]" id="book_author">
          <option value='' selected></option>
        </select>
      </td>

      <td>
        <input type="number" step=0.01 name="book_amount[]"/>
      </td>
  
      <td>
        <button type="button" id="add">Add</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Update:
So upon tinkering and following some advice, I was able to populate the second drop down or the newly created drop down with values.

I changed this code

```
      jQuery.getJSON(json_url, function(data) {
      // empty contents of dropdown
      $("#book_title").html("");
      $("#book_title").append("<option value='' selected></option>");
      // put new dropdown values to dropdown
      jQuery.each(data, function(key, val) {
        $("#book_title").append('<option value="' + val.book_title + '"data-book_title_id="' + val.book_title_id + ' ">' + val.book_title + '</option>')
      });
    });

  $("#add").click(function(e) {
    if (x <= maxRows) {
      $("#book_table").append(html);
      x++;
    }
  });
```

To this code:

```
  $("#book_table").on('click', '#add', function(e) {
      if (x <= maxRows) {
  $("#book_table").append(html);
  x++;
}

  $.getJSON(json_url, function(data) {
  // empty contents of drop down

  $(".book_title").append("<option value='' selected></option>");
  // put new drop down values to drop down
  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    $(".book_title").append('<option value="' + val.book_title + '"data-book_title_id="' + val.book_title_id + ' ">' + val.book_title + '</option>')
  });
});
```

});

I changed the book_title from ID to Class selector as per @nivendha advice, I also use .on(), now the problem is 
  first: every time I add another select field, the previous selected value from the drop down was being reset, this may be due to this code:

```
 $(".book_title").append("<option value='' selected></option>");
```

Though when I removed that piece of code, it would not populate the drop down.

second: the initial select field does not contain or being populated with values, only the newly created select field upon clicking the add button.

third: the data or value that populates the select field, is being looped or repeated on the preceding select value. Let say upon adding a newly created select field, the drop down was being populated with a, b, c then upon creating a new select field, the previous select field would now become a,b,c,a,b,c then the second one would be a,b,c and then upon the creation of another select field, the first field would now become a,b,c,a,b,c,a,b,c and the second one would be a,b,c,a,b,c and the third one is a,b,c it would go on and on every time I add another select field.

Another update:
Ok now I solved the second issue, by completely removing this piece of code,

```
$(".book_title").append("<option value='' selected></option>");
```

And about the third issue, I guess it is because it keeps on appending the json value even if there is already value in there, if only there is a way to limit or append only if it is empty.

Answer (score 0):

save the `html` in a `htmlElement` and use it to append for `add`

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  var maxRows = 100;
  var x = 1;
  var json_url = "books_json.php";
  var htmlElement;
  var html = '';
  html += '<tr>';
  html += '<td>';
  html += '<select name="book_title[]" class="book_title">';
  html += '<option value="" selected></option>';
  html += '</select>';
  html += '</td>';
  html += '<td>';
  html += '<select name="book_author[]" class="book_author">';
  html += '<option value="" selected></option>';
  html += '</select>';
  html += '</td>';
  html += '<td>';
  html += '<input type="number" step=0.01 name="amount[]"/>';
  html += '</td>';
  html += '<td>';
  html += '<button type="button" class="remove">Remove</button>';
  html += '</td>';
  html += '</tr>';

  jQuery.getJSON(json_url, function(data) {
    // empty contents of dropdown
    $(html).find(".book_title").html("");
    $(html).find(".book_title").append("<option value='' selected></option>");
    // put new dropdown values to dropdown
    jQuery.each(data, function(key, val) {
      $(html).find(".book_title").append('<option value="' + val.book_title + '"data-book_title_id="' + val.book_title_id + ' ">' + val.book_title + '</option>')
    });
    htmlElement = $(html);

    $(".add").click(function(e) {
      if (x <= maxRows) {
        $("#book_table").append(htmlElement);
        x++;
      }
    });

    $(".book_table").on('click', '.remove', function(e) {
      $(this).closest('tr').remove();
      x--;
    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='book_table'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Author</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select name="book_title[]" id="book_title">
          <option value='' selected></option>
        </select>
      </td>

      <td>
        <select name="book_author[]" id="book_author">
          <option value='' selected></option>
        </select>
      </td>

      <td>
        <input type="number" step=0.01 name="book_amount[]" />
      </td>

      <td>
        <button type="button" id="add">Add</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

PS: i updated `id` to `class` for `book_title` and others

Comment: Im not sure I follow, but I will try to understand it , and try it if it works.

Comment: Hi, the add button does not work or append the htmlElement, anyway upon reading about binding dynamic content, it all leads to using .on() though I am not sure how to.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this would help.Try like this instead of passing json value to select box.

```
<?php//Select * from table(books); //Convert it to query 
 $output = '';
foreach($results as $row){
 $output .= '<option value="'.$row["book_title_id"].'">'.$row["book_title_name"].'</option>'; ?>
```

and html table look like this

```
<table id='book_table' class="book_table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Author</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th><input type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="addrow" value="+" /></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <a class="deleteRow"></a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and the script. Make sure to add **jquery library**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
var counter = 0;

    $("#addrow").on("click", function () {

        counter = $('#book_table tr').length - 2;

        var newRow = $("<tr>");
        var cols = "";

        cols += '<td><select class="book-title form-control" name="book_title[]" data-title_id="'+counter+'" id="book_title' + counter + '"><option>Select Book Title</option><?php echo $output; ?></select></td>';

        cols += '<td><select class="book-author form-control" name="book_author[]" data-book_author="'+counter+'" id="book_author' + counter + '"><option>Select Book Author</option><?php echo $authorOutput; ?></select></td>';

        cols += '<td><input class="form-control amount" type="number" name="amount[]" id="amount' + counter + '"/></td>';

        cols += '<td><input type="button" class="ibtnDel btn btn-danger"  value="-"></td>';
        newRow.append(cols);
        if (counter == 5) {
          alert("You've reached the limit");
          $('#addrow').attr('disabled', true).prop('value', "+");
       }
        $("table.order-list").append(newRow);
        counter++;
    });

//In case if you want to do any functionality for selected options

    $("table.book_table").on("change", '.book-title', function (event) {
      //alert(event);
        var bookValue = $(this).val(); // to get the current selected items
        var bookId = $(this).data("title_id"); // to get the i

        $.ajax({
            url: "url",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "HTML",
            data: {bookValue: bookValue},
          success:function(data)
          {
            var amout  = JSON.parse(data);
            $('#amount'+bookId).val(amount); //in case if you want to place the value in amount after selecting the book name
          }
        })    
    });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I am trying to apply this but I cannot make it work.