# MYSQL / PHP - Website displaying Null Table values

Tags: php, mysql, null

I am trying to get data from PHP Mysql to display on my webpage, it seems to return the correct number of rows for the query (3) but always displays nulls on the webpage.

Any ideas where I am going wrong.

READ PHP

```
   // stocks array
    $stocks_arr=array();
    $stocks_arr["stocks"]=array();
 
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        extract($row);
        $stocks_item=array(
        "user_name" => $stocks->user_name,
        "user_id" => $stocks->user_id,
        "user_stock1" => $stocks->user_stock1,
        "user_stock1_pl" => $stocks->user_stock1_pl,
        "user_stock1_price" => $stocks->user_stock1_price,
        "user_stock1_amount" => $stocks->user_stock1_amount,
        "user_stock1_live_price" => $stocks->user_stock1_live_price
        );
        array_push($stocks_arr["stocks"], $stocks_item);
    }
 
    echo json_encode($stocks_arr["stocks"]);
}
else{
    echo json_encode(array());
}
?>
```

INDEX.PHP

```
?>
<!-- page script -->
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../api/stocks_dashboard/read.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            var response="";
            for(var user in data){
                response += "<tr>"+
                "<td>"+data[user].user_stock1+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+data[user].user_stock1_pl+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+data[user].user_stock1_price+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+data[user].user_stock1_amount+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+data[user].user_stock1_live_price+"</td>"+
                "<td><a href='update.php?id="+data[user].user_stock1+"'>Edit</a> | <a href='#' onClick=Remove('"+data[user].user_stock1+"')>Remove</a></td>"+
                "</tr>";
            }
            $(response).appendTo($("#stocks"));
        }
    });
  });
```

[null rows displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEtuM.png)

Comment: Where is `$stocks` defined and what does it actually contain? I also don't see the point of using `extract()` here?

Comment: Good point. you might be able to remove the while loop and instead just do
`echo json_encode($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))`

Comment: Also, `data[user]` makes no since since you're just returning `$stocks_arr["stocks"]` (which is an indexed array). There are many oddities here. I would recommend that you take a step back, do one thing at the time and make sure that the data looks like and contains what you expect before continuing trying to use it later on.

Comment: @draxiom - That would just give them one row. They should rather use `->fetchAll()`, but honestly, the JS will still be wrong. And unless `$stocks` is one of the extracted variables, I don't see them actually using the database result at all. And if it is one of the extracted variables, I doubt it will be an object (which is what they are using it as). There are way too many unclear things going on here.

Comment: Agreed. I will edit my "answer" to talk about those problems as well

Comment: I realize that `data[user]` does make sense since they are simply using `user` as the index for the array. It was the naming `user` that threw me off (since it's basically just an array index). The PHP part is still odd though.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with this code. First, in your php script, you seem to be unnecessarily looping through the results of a db query, saving the data to a new array with the wrong key ($stocks instead of $row), and then returning that as json. Instead, you can directly encode the result from the db without any additional loops.
Here is a link to a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2770300/11767474
your read.php script would look like this

```
echo json_encode($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

The next issue is how you're trying to extract the data in the ajax/js loop. I believe the for-in loop you're using gives you the actual object, and not the index to the object. So user should end up being each individual user in that array. I'd `console.log(user)` and `console.log(data)` to verify the data is being parsed as json. The display should look like this:

```
            for(var user in data){
                console.log(user);
                response += "<tr>"+
                "<td>"+user.user_stock1+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+user.user_stock1_pl+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+user.user_stock1_price+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+user.user_stock1_amount+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+user.user_stock1_live_price+"</td>"+
                "<td><a href='update.php?id="+user.user_stock1+"'>Edit</a> | <a href='#' onClick=Remove('"+user.user_stock1+"')>Remove</a></td>"+
                "</tr>";
            }
            $(response).appendTo($("#stocks"));
```

Comment: Thanks, when using console.log it states "undefined" instead of "null"

Comment: ah. ok. so I bet `data` is not getting cast as a json object, and is instead a string. First console.log(data) to see that there is something returning. And then use `JSON.parse()` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to cast the string as a json object before the for loop

Comment: `user` here would be the array index (an integer) so `user.whatever` wouldn't work.